# Create a list from json file, with multiple values

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq

I'm trying to get all the data from a json file however I have problems to filter out missing objects without one out of two values (EMAIL,JOB_TITLE).

Here's the json :
`[{"primary": "JOHN DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name":"BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value":"john.doe@contoso.com"}, {"type": "string", "name": "JOB_TITLE", "value": "SALESMAN"} ], "aliases": [{"alias": "joao.doe@contoso.com"}]},{"primary": "LORRAINE DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": 456}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "STATUS", "value": "Unavaliable"}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value": "lorraine.doe@contoso.com"}, {"type": "string", "name": "JOB_TITLE", "value": "SECRETARY"} ], "aliases": [{"alias": "lorris.doe@contoso.com"}, {"alias": "lorris2.doe@contoso.com"}]},{"primary": "JACK DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name":"JOB_TITLE", "value": "OWNER"}], "aliases": [{"alias":"jack.doe@contoso.com"},{"alias": "jackson.doe@contoso.com"}]}, {"primary": "NOAH DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value": "noah.doe@contoso.com"}], "aliases": [{"alias": "noah.doe95@contoso.com"}]}]`

The list that I try to create:

```
"john.doe@contoso.com": "SALESMAN",
"lorraine.doe@contoso.com": "SECRETARY"
```

The code that I used:

> echo '[{"primary": "JOHN DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name":"BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value":"john.doe@contoso.com"}, {"type": "string", "name": "JOB_TITLE", "value": "SALESMAN"} ], "aliases": [{"alias": "joao.doe@contoso.com"}]},{"primary": "LORRAINE DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": 456}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "STATUS", "value": "Unavaliable"}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value": "lorraine.doe@contoso.com"}, {"type": "string", "name": "JOB_TITLE", "value": "SECRETARY"} ], "aliases": [{"alias": "lorris.doe@contoso.com"}, {"alias": "lorris2.doe@contoso.com"}]},{"primary": "JACK DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name":"JOB_TITLE", "value": "OWNER"}], "aliases": [{"alias":"jack.doe@contoso.com"},{"alias": "jackson.doe@contoso.com"}]}, {"primary": "NOAH DOE", "attributes": [{"type": "double", "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER", "value": "123"}, {"type": "double", "name": "FLOOR", "value": 10}, {"type": "string", "name": "EMAIL", "value": "noah.doe@contoso.com"}], "aliases": [{"alias": "noah.doe95@contoso.com"}]}]' | jq '.[].attributes[]|select(.name|contains("JOB_TITLE"), contains ("EMAIL"))' | jq .value | sed 'N;s/\n/:/' | sed 's/$/,/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns the attributes array into an object using `from_entries`, filters according to the presence of both keys using `select` and `has`, and extracts the values required using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29):

```bash
jq -r '
  .[].attributes | from_entries
  | select(has("JOB_TITLE") and has("EMAIL"))
  | "\"\(.EMAIL)\": \"\(.JOB_TITLE)\""
'
```

```json
"john.doe@contoso.com": "SALESMAN"
"lorraine.doe@contoso.com": "SECRETARY"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TxSfaILGvfh)

Comment: I see in [the source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L42) that `from_entries` uses `.key` OR `.name` but it's [not documented](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries). How did you know that would work?

Comment: @glennjackman I really don't remember when I did learn about the variants. Probably by looking at the `builtin.jq` every now and then, but there's also an [issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1220) and another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757559/jq-from-entries-function-works-with-key-but-not-name) pointing it out... In fact, in my [first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/74215028/1) I created an `INDEX(.name)` myself, and referenced the values using `.EMAIL.value` and `.JOB_TITLE.value`.