# Using Select to filter in jq query

Tags: json, key, jq

previously I posted a question here ([Create a list from json file, with multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74214912/create-a-list-from-json-file-with-multiple-values/74215028#74215028)). However, I found some of my keys are outdated, and they contain a key called "end". I was not able to filter them out, making the data erratic.

Here's the updated JSON that I use for testing:

```json
[
  {
    "primary": "JOHN DOE",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "FLOOR",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "EMAIL",
        "value": "john.doe@contoso.com"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "SALESMAN"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "TRAINEE",
        "end": "11-09-2022"
      }
    ],
    "aliases": [
      {
        "alias": "joao.doe@contoso.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "primary": "LORRAINE DOE",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER",
        "value": 456
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "FLOOR",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "STATUS",
        "value": "Unavaliable"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "EMAIL",
        "value": "lorraine.doe@contoso.com"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "Procurement",
        "end": "11-09-2021"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "SECRETARY"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "SALES",
        "end": "11-09-2021"
      }
    ],
    "aliases": [
      {
        "alias": "lorris.doe@contoso.com"
      },
      {
        "alias": "lorris2.doe@contoso.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "primary": "JACK DOE",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "FLOOR",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "JOB_TITLE",
        "value": "OWNER"
      }
    ],
    "aliases": [
      {
        "alias": "jack.doe@contoso.com"
      },
      {
        "alias": "jackson.doe@contoso.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "primary": "NOAH DOE",
    "attributes": [
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "BUILDING_NUMBER",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "type": "double",
        "name": "FLOOR",
        "value": 10
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "name": "EMAIL",
        "value": "noah.doe@contoso.com"
      }
    ],
    "aliases": [
      {
        "alias": "noah.doe95@contoso.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there a way to filter out the attributes with key "end" and make the result as below?

```
"john.doe@contoso.com": "SALESMAN",
"lorraine.doe@contoso.com": "SECRETARY"
```

This is the old solution:

```
.[].attributes | from_entries
| select(has("JOB_TITLE") and has("EMAIL"))
| "\"\(.EMAIL)\": \"\(.JOB_TITLE)\""
```

Comment: Thank you both pmf and knittl, both worked flawlessly

Comment: The difference between the two solutions is whether attributes that contain an `.end` field but are not `.name`d as `JOB_TITLE` should be filtered out as well or not. If there are no such attributes in your data, both solutions will produce the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter them out using a `map` before running `from_entries`:

```bash
.[].attributes 
| map(select(.name != "JOB_TITLE" or (has("end") | not)))
| from_entries
| select(has("JOB_TITLE") and has("EMAIL"))
| "\"\(.EMAIL)\": \"\(.JOB_TITLE)\""
```

```json
"john.doe@contoso.com": "SALESMAN"
"lorraine.doe@contoso.com": "SECRETARY"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HMhq5mw0tHa)

Comment: Offtopic: I see your answers here regarding `jq` and really appreciate them :) Can you recommend some good tutorial/articles how to learn `jq` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks, I'm glad my answers are helpful. As for tutorials, I found the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) quite satisfying as it touches all topics, albeit sometimes short of better examples. Also looking at the builtins [implemented](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) in jq itself helped a lot to catch on certain expressions and techniques. For the rest, just try actively solving simple tasks. Actually, this is what brought me here last year after discovering jq, as SO is an ideal place to learn by solving simplified real-life problems.

Comment: @AndrejKesely - See also the jq FAQ and in particular the section on Tutorials: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#tutorials

Answer (score 2):

Before converting the attributes to objects, select only those which do not have an `end` property:

```
.[].attributes
| map(select(has("end")|not)) # <- this line is new
| from_entries
| select(has("JOB_TITLE") and has("EMAIL"))
| "\"\(.EMAIL)\": \"\(.JOB_TITLE)\""
```

Output:

```
"john.doe@contoso.com": "SALESMAN"
"lorraine.doe@contoso.com": "SECRETARY"
```